# Javascript - targeting p tags within a div not returning anything

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I have two divs with class of "thing". I want to access all the p tags within them using them using javascript and change their color. This is what I'm trying but it's not working:

```
<div id="top" class="thing">
    <p>kdjflksj siuiotue</p>
    <p>kdjflksj siuiotue</p>
    <p>kdjflksj siuiotue</p>    

</div>
```

Javascript

```
   var changes = document.getElementsByClassName("thing");
   var pchanges = changes.getElementsByTagName("p");

   for(let i = 0; i < pchanges.length; i++) {

    pchanges[i].onmouseover = function() {

        this.style.color = "blue";
    }

    pchanges[i].onmouseout = function(){
        this.style.color = "black";
    }

}
```

The javascript is within a window.onload function.

Comment: Before we actually solve the problem you are having-- are you sure this is how you want to approach it?  The color changing on hover you are looking to do is much more cleanly achieved using CSS `:hover` pseudo-class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `changes` is an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which doesn't have a `getElementsByTagName` method. You would have to call that method on each element inside the collection to get what you want. However, this looks like a good place to use `document.querySelectorAll` instead, so that you can get the elements you want in a single call:

```js
var pchanges = document.querySelectorAll(".thing p");

for(let i = 0; i < pchanges.length; i++) {
    pchanges[i].onmouseover = function() {
        this.style.color = "blue";
    }

    pchanges[i].onmouseout = function(){
        this.style.color = "black";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="top" class="thing">
    <p>kdjflksj siuiotue</p>
    <p>kdjflksj siuiotue</p>
    <p>kdjflksj siuiotue</p>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('#top p')
```